# Communicating between extension and python program

Tags: javascript, python, web, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a program that requires a chrome extension and a python program. As it stores sensitive data, I'd prefer if it did not use a server-side database and instead store everything locally if possible. I saw that there are two possible ways to communicate between an extension and a python program. The first way is through native messaging. In pursuit of this I did the regedit to create a key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.program.name`. I added the following code to the extension:

```
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.program.name',
    { text: "Hello, native messaging host!" },
     function(response) {
         console.log("Sent message:", { text: "Hello, native messaging host!" });
         console.log("Received response from native messaging host:", response);
    }
);
```

And the matching python program:

```
import struct
import sys
import json
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=r'C:\\Users\\me\\IDE\\project\\subfolder\\logfile.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('Native messaging host started')

def send_message(message):
    # Encode message length as 4 byte unsigned integer.
    message = json.dumps(message)
    encoded_length = struct.pack('@I', len(message))
    # Write message length and content.
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(encoded_length)
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(message.encode('utf-8'))
    sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
    logging.debug('Sent message: %s', message)

def read_message():
    # Read the message length (first 4 bytes).
    text_length_bytes = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
    if len(text_length_bytes) == 0:
        sys.exit(0)
    # Unpack message length as 4 byte unsigned integer.
    text_length = struct.unpack('@I', text_length_bytes)[0]
    # Read the text (JSON object) of the message.
    text = sys.stdin.buffer.read(text_length).decode('utf-8')
    logging.debug('Received message: %s', text)
    return json.loads(text)

while True:
    message = read_message()
    send_message({"message": "data"})
```

The manifest file for the native message host:

```
{
  "name": "com.program.name",
  "description": "Description",
  "path": 
"C:\\Users\\me\\IDE\\project\\subfolder\\program.py",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "brave-extension://id/",
    "chrome-extension://id/"
  ]
}
```

But when I look at the log file it is empty.

The web console for the extension displays the following errors:
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Specified native messaging host not found.` and `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Specified native messaging host not found.` I also get the following two notifications: `Sent message: Object text: "Hello, native messaging host!"` and `Received response from native messaging host: undefined`. With the log file empty and the errors in the console, it seems like this does not work.

The second method I used was using selenium to access the localstorage:

To do this I used the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import selenium

print(selenium.__version__)
# Set up the webdriver options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.binary_location = 'C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe'

# Set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Navigate to the page that uses Web Storage
driver.get("brave-extension://id/options.html")

# Access localStorage
local_storage = driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage;")

# Access sessionStorage
session_storage = driver.execute_script("return window.sessionStorage;")

# Access a specific key in localStorage
key_value = driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.getItem('Data');")

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

With the corresponding code in my extension (background.js):

```
chrome.storage.local.set({Data: data});
```

But here I get the following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <unknown>: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.`

I am not wedded to any particular approach. I just care that I am able to communicate between the web browser and the local environment in an efficient way.

Comment: Maybe you should specify a .bat file in "path" that runs your .py script because this is how it's done in the existing examples of nativeMessaging + python.